# wso2is session timeouts only working with 'Remember Me', otherwise default to 15 minutes

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have wso2is 5+SP1 setup to persist sessions per https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Enabling+Authentication+Session+Persistence

However, users that *have not* selected 'Remember Me' will be forced to re-authenticate by wso2is after 15 minutes. These users have their commonAuthId cookie set w/ no expiration time (end of browsing session). Users that *have* selected 'Remember Me' will get their commonAuthId cookie set with the configured 24 hour expiration time and won't be prompted for re-authorization after 15 minutes.

In both scenarios it appears that session serialization / caching is working correctly, since both commonAuthId values will be stored in the IDN_AUTH_SESSION_STORE table of the backing database.

For the non-RememberMe, the log looks like this:

```
[2015-07-17 08:16:00,257] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  retrieving authentication request from cache.. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
[2015-07-17 08:16:00,258] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Initializing the flow {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
[2015-07-17 08:16:00,258] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Framework contextId: 07084e16-7dd9-4726-bf9c-a9a42b06dfe1 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
[2015-07-17 08:16:00,258] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Starting an authentication flow {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
[2015-07-17 08:16:00,259] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl} -  Loading Basic Application Data of default {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
[2015-07-17 08:16:00,260] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  commonAuthId cookie is available with the value: 4536ad78-26f5-44cb-97bb-080dfc319d13 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
[2015-07-17 08:16:00,260] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.CacheImpl} -  Using local cache {org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.CacheImpl}
[2015-07-17 08:16:00,285] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Failed to find the SessionContext from the cache. Possible cache timeout. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
```

That last line is the failure of

`SessionContext sessionContext = FrameworkUtils.getSessionContextFromCache(cookie
                    .getValue());`

in `DefaultRequestCoordinator`. I'm just not sure why it returns null for non-RememberMe users. In contrast, here's the log from a RememberMe user:

```
[2015-07-20 12:37:47,123] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  retrieving authentication request from cache.. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
[2015-07-20 12:37:47,123] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Initializing the flow {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
[2015-07-20 12:37:47,123] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Framework contextId: a6bb7032-e089-4e8f-8ca4-c2f790a767f4 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
[2015-07-20 12:37:47,123] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Starting an authentication flow {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
[2015-07-20 12:37:47,127] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  commonAuthId cookie is available with the value: c2b28178-ddcb-4156-b258-4e0fb5ffcdb8 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
[2015-07-20 12:37:47,127] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Service Provider is: default {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
[2015-07-20 12:37:47,127] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  A previously authenticated sequence found for the SP: default {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
[2015-07-20 12:37:47,127] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Already authenticated by username: dillon {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
```

Here's the relevant sections of our identity.xml and web.xml that have the timeouts set. Our datastore is an Oracle db.

identity.xml:

```
<SessionDataPersist>
        <PoolSize>0</PoolSize>
        <Enable>true</Enable>
        <RememberMePeriod>1440</RememberMePeriod>
        <CleanUp>
                <Enable>true</Enable>
                <Period>30</Period>
                <TimeOut>720</TimeOut>
        </CleanUp>
        <Temporary>false</Temporary>
</SessionDataPersist>
...
<SessionContextCache>
        <Enable>true</Enable>
        <Capacity>100000</Capacity>
</SessionContextCache>
```

web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>720</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

In WSO2 IS, you can set the SSO session cookie timeout value in /repository/conf/identity/identity.xml file

you can find the below config.

```
<TimeConfig>
        <SessionIdleTimeout>15</SessionIdleTimeout>
................
```